# Please select the build variants to build and sign. android studio error

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to get an APK output from Android Studio, I get this error when I click the Finish button. Can you tell me what to do to get it right? It should be noted that I was getting my output normally but after a while it gave this error.

> Please select the build variants to build and sign

This is my screenshot error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select "release" from the list before clicking finish button

Comment: Thank you very much! fixed!

Comment: If that fixed your problem, click on the check mark beside the answer to accept the answer, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

please the select release
Your problem will be solved
And after that, select your application in the target path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).